# Multiple styles() applied to the same row with package openxlsx

Tags: r, openxlsx

I started using the `R` package `openxlsx` recently because it does not require the `rJava` package or Java at all.  I'm trying to write dates to a column but row formatting isn't being applied to the final date column in my `xlsx` file.

Example data:

```
tmp <- structure(list(someNumbers = c(8L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
       7L, 2L), someLetters = structure(c(9L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
       6L, 8L, 5L), .Label = c("b", "d", "e", "h", "l", "n", "o", "t", 
       "u"), class = "factor"), moreNumbers = c(25L, 25L, 36L, 38L, 
       39L, 32L, 31L, 40L, 28L, 32L), moreStuff = c(0.37, 1.39, -2.27, 
       0.65, -0.71, -1.67, 0.71, 1.32, 2.14, 1.13), words = structure(c(5L, 
       3L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 10L, 9L, 8L), .Label = c("And another, but      
       maybe I'll make this one a little bit longer.", 
       "camera", "cat", "Ceramic penil holder made by yours truly.", 
       "dog", "headset", "Here's a list of words, almost like a    
       description.", 
       "Last", "Number 9.  Number 9.  Number 9.", "This phrase is not six     
       words long."
       ), class = "factor"), dates = structure(c(2000, 3217.55555555556, 
       4435.11111111111, 5652.66666666667, 6870.22222222222,     
       8087.77777777778, 
       9305.33333333333, 10522.8888888889, 11740.4444444444, 12958), class =    
       "Date")), .Names = c("someNumbers", 
       "someLetters", "moreNumbers", "moreStuff", "words", "dates"),    
       row.names = c(NA, 
       -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

and code:

```
#Setting date options
options("openxlsx.dateFormat" = "yyyy-mm-dd")

#Create the xlsx workbook and insert a worksheet
testing <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(testing, "openxlsxTesting")

#Set column widths
setColWidths(testing, "openxlsxTesting", cols = 1:ncol(tmp), widths =    
"auto")

#Create a header style
headerStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "white", fgFill =  
"blue", halign = "left", valign = "center", textDecoration =  
"bold")

#Create styles to shade alternate rows
lightStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "black", fgFill = "#E7E0C5", halign = 
"right", valign = "center")

darkStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "black", fgFill = "#E1D8B7", halign =  
"right", valign = "center")


#A vector of the xlsx rows
colorRows <- 2:(nrow(tmp)+1)

#Apply the header style
addStyle(testing, "openxlsxTesting", headerStyle, rows = 1, cols = 
1:ncol(tmp), gridExpand = TRUE)

#Apply the alternate shading styles
addStyle(testing, "openxlsxTesting", lightStyle, rows  = 
colorRows[which(colorRows %% 2 == 0)], cols = 1:ncol(tmp), gridExpand = TRUE)

addStyle(testing, "openxlsxTesting", darkStyle, rows =  
colorRows[which(colorRows %% 2 == 1)], cols = 1:ncol(tmp), gridExpand = TRUE)

#Write data to the workbook
writeData(testing, "openxlsxTesting", tmp, startRow = 1, startCol = 1)

#Save workbook to getwd()
saveWorkbook(testing, "openXlsxTesting.xlsx", TRUE)
```

What I end up with is the image below which is *almost* formatted correctly, but the date column lacks the shaded colors.

[image: screen shot of .xlsx file]

Am I missing something?  I've read the documentation but I can't figure out a way to apply formatting to date fields.  I've tried specifically formatting the date column, then running `addStyle()` after applying date formatting, but it's still a no go.

How is it that the `addStyle()` function isn't applying the `lightStyle` or `darkStyle` to the date column?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found a work-around: if I convert any `Date` fields to `as.character()`, the `addStyles()` works across all rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The styling is being overwritten by the date column styling.  Calling writeData() before adding any styles and setting stack = TRUE when calling addStyle() will fix this. I'll make a code change on github
https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx to prevent styles being overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wasn't aware that `writeData()` should be called before `addStyle()`.