# Different date format when export to excel from R using Openxslx addstyle function

Tags: r, export-to-excel, openxlsx

I have a tibble called "quotation". I want to highlight some rows based on certain condition (i.e. having specific text). I can format by slicing rows that containing the text (as data.frame) and highlight entire rows by using addStyle().

However, when I save the workbook and open it in excel, I find that the highlighted rows have general format (instead of date/custom format). Other rows have normal date as in R, which can be seen in this picture [image: worksheet showing different date format].

Any advise on that?

```
wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "quotation")

writeDataTable(wb, "quotation", x = quotation)
   
red <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000",
                         fgFill = "#CC2222")

yellow <- createStyle(fontColour = "#000000",
                         fgFill = "#FFFF00")

redRows = data.frame(which(quotation$note == "no", arr.ind=TRUE))
yellowRows = data.frame(which(quotation$note == "late", arr.ind=TRUE))

# Apply style:
addStyle(wb, "quotation", cols = 1:ncol(quotation), rows = redRows[,1]+1,
         style = highlight0, gridExpand = TRUE)
addStyle(wb, "quotation", cols = 1:ncol(quotation), rows = yellowRows[,1]+1,
         style = highlight, gridExpand = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "data.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for the problem from this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244303/multiple-styles-applied-to-the-same-row-with-package-openxlsx). I need to set `stack = True` in addStyle() function to keep previous style (including date format) not overwritten by the highlight styles.